# C++ running slow when compiled from commandline

Tags: c++, g++

So I've written a C++ program in Codeblocks, a program that usually takes some time to run (in code blocks, one iteration takes about 70 seconds). Now I've tried running the same .cpp file from PowerShell (with the intent of later trying to run the same program multiple times in parallel). However, running the resulting program in PowerShell (or `cmd.exe`) takes 10 times longer, i.e **700+** seconds. Any idea what is happening, why does this take so much longer than Codeblocks?

Steps I've taken:

1. changed the path in powerShell to the directory where the .cpp file is.
2. `g++ file.cpp -o file.exe`
3. `.\file.exe`

That is all I've done. At first, I thought it will never stop, since it took so long, but I've done this 3 times, and every time it took 700 - 750 seconds to run, which is 10 times longer than it would take simply building and running the program from CodeBlocks?

Any hints and ideas? I really need to make it work from the console, and be able to run multiple instances, since the code for some parameters will take 5+ hours to run.

**EDIT:**
Following the advice from here, I used some g++ specific flags:

```
g++ -O3 -s main.cpp -o main.exe
```

and managed to reduce the running time to around 180 seconds; still haven't figured out how to get the same time I get when running the program from codeblocks.

Comment: Do a release / optimised build and test that.  Compare the command line switches that Code::Blocks is using compared to the command line used above.

Comment: Why do you compile `file.cpp` every time the script runs? Compiling and linking a c++-program can take quite long compared to other languages like java. Once it has been compiled, it usually runs very fast compared to other languages.

Comment: Does it also take 700+ seconds if you launch `file.exe` from `cmd.exe`? If so, it's not PowerShell-related, but `g++`-related :)

Comment: Indeed, in Codeblocks I was in Release mode. But how do I do a release build from the console?

I only compiled file.cpp first, then I simply ran it. And it took 700+ seconds

Yep, it also took 700 seconds from cmd as well.

Comment: @Lucian Give gcc's [optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) a go: `g++ -O2 -s file.cpp -o file.exe` or `g++ -O3 file.cpp -o file.exe`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I used those (also tried other combinations) and it helped, the time decreased to 180 seconds. But sadly it is still way slower than the CodeBlocks.

Comment: @Lucian It's been quite a while since I've used Codeblocks, but see if you can't find the settings for "build options" or "compiler options", you might be able to find the exact flags it's passing to the compiler by default

Comment: In the compiler settings I can only see -O2 and -s, which I've tried and it still goes slower.

Comment: So I tried something new: I copy pasted the commands from the build logs from Codeblocks into the PowerShell console, and then ran the file.exe executable. I still got 180 seconds. 
So even if I used the same build specs as codeblocks uses, when running the file from the console it takes more than twice as much time. No idea what is happening

Comment: If your programm outputs very much, it is possible that your programm is limited by the speed of the terminal.

Comment: It only writes 7-8 lines  into a .txt file.

Comment: @Lucian i mean output to the commandline.

Comment: @Lucian -- in the 7-8 lines that it writes into the file, change `std::endl` to `'\n'`. It might not be the difference between the two, but let the file-handling code manage buffer flushes.